# How can I block myself from time-wasting sites, particularly with Google Incognito?

Tags: google-chrome, incognito-mode

I have a bad habit when I'm waiting for code to compile or a database query to run, I may pop over to a news site for a minute.

I have a Chrome extension that blocks certain time-wasters, but now I'll just go to incognito mode and that's a 2-second way to get around it.

Is there another option to make it more difficult for myself to go to certain websites?

I know nothing is fool proof, obviously, I just need a slightly more annoying barrier. My apologies if this question is off-topic; I consider it a technical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the extensions which block these websites in incognito mode.

Simply go to *Settings* > *More tools* > *Extensions* and check the *Allow in incognito* boxes.

Comment: Didn't know this - sounds like a great help, thanks!